# Flutter no encuentra el Provider<DirectionProvider>

Tags: flutter

como andan? estoy trabajando con Google Maps, en esta oportunidad, me encuentro con el siguiente error: (Provider)

**[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this GoogleMaps Widget**

Y la clase con la que estoy trabajando es la siguiente: (una parte, para no hacerla larga):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'DirectionProvider.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class GoogleMaps extends StatefulWidget {
  final String x, y;
  GoogleMaps(this.x, this.y);
  final LatLng fromPoint = LatLng(-37.020125, -62.409388);

  static ChangeNotifierProvider init(double x, double y) =>  ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => new DirectionProvider(),
  );

  @override
  _GoogleMapsState createState() => _GoogleMapsState();
}

class _GoogleMapsState extends State<GoogleMaps> {
  Position _currentPosition;
  LatLng toPoint;

  void initState() {
    _getCurrentLocation();
    var x2 = double.parse(widget.x);
    var y2 = double.parse(widget.y);
    toPoint = new LatLng(x2, y2);
    super.initState();
  }

  GoogleMapController _mapController;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Google Maps'),
      ),
      body:  Consumer<DirectionProvider>(
        builder: (_,api,__) {
          return GoogleMap(
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: widget.fromPoint,
              zoom: 12,
            ),
            markers: _createMarkers(),
            polylines: api.currentRoute,
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.zoom_out_map),
        onPressed: _centerView,
      ),
    );
  }

  Set<Marker> _createMarkers() {
    var tmp = Set<Marker>();

    tmp.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId("FromPoint"),
      position: widget.fromPoint,
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "estoy aca"),
    ));

    tmp.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId("toPoint"),
      position: toPoint,
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "llegada"),
    ));
    return tmp;
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _mapController = controller;

    _centerView();
  }

  _centerView() async {
    var api = Provider.of<DirectionProvider>(context);

    await _mapController.getVisibleRegion();

    print("buscando direcciones");
    await api.findDirections(widget.fromPoint, toPoint);

    var left = min(
        widget.fromPoint.latitude, toPoint.latitude); //SE CALCULA COORDENADAS.
    var right = max(widget.fromPoint.latitude, toPoint.latitude);
    var top = max(widget.fromPoint.longitude, toPoint.longitude);
    var bottom = min(widget.fromPoint.longitude, toPoint.longitude);

    api.currentRoute.first.points.forEach((point) {
      left = min(left, point.latitude);
      right = max(right, point.latitude);
      top = max(top, point.longitude);
      bottom = min(bottom, point.longitude);
    });

    var bounds = LatLngBounds(
      southwest: LatLng(left, bottom),
      northeast: LatLng(right, top),
    );
    var cameraUpdate = CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50);
    _mapController.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
  }


  _getCurrentLocation() {
    var geolocator = Geolocator();
    var locationOptions = LocationOptions(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, distanceFilter: 10);

    StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream = geolocator.getPositionStream(locationOptions).listen((Position position) {
          print(position == null ? 'Unknown' : position.latitude.toString() + ', ' + position.longitude.toString());
        });
  }
}
```

No puedo encontrar, sinceramente el error.
Muchas gracias de antemano.
Ya Ejecute Flutter Clean.
También esta la clase DirectionProvider, pero en ésta, simplemente esta al api key y se calcula cual es el mejor camino para llegar a destino.

(se actualizo)

el widget con el que es llamada GoogleMaps es un InkWell

```
return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GoogleMaps(x,y));
        Navigator.push(context, route);
      },
```

Comment: has intentado limpiar el proyecto con : flutter clean?  y fijarte si has importado las librerias correspondientes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que estás usando el `Consumer` directamente en el mismo contexto del `Provider` que creaste, lo podrías solucionar de varias formas, una de ellas es que declares el `ChangeNotifierProvider` encima del widget que tienes declarado en tu pregunta (como parent).

La otra es que uses el widget `Builder` para crear un nuevo contexto.

```dart
           body:ChangeNotifierProvider(
           create: (_) => new DirectionProvider(),
           child: Builder(
              builder : (context) => Consumer<DirectionProvider>(
             builder:
                 (BuildContext context, DirectionProvider api, Widget child) {
               return GoogleMap(
                 initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                   target: widget.fromPoint,
                   zoom: 12,
                 ),
                 markers: _createMarkers(),
                 polylines: api.currentRoute,
                onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                 myLocationEnabled: true,
                 myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
              );
             },
           ),
  ) ,
)
```

**UPDATED**

El problema que tienes es por el contexto como lo dije anteriormente, estás usando Provider.of con un contexto local, para solucionar el problema la manera más adecuada es sacar el ChangeNotifierProvider y ponerlo arriba, ahora para llamar al widget de google maps, ya no haces esto:

```dart
GoogleMaps(123, 456)
```

sino esto

```dart
GoogleMaps.init(123,456)
```

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'DirectionProvider.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class GoogleMaps extends StatefulWidget {
  final String x, y;
  GoogleMaps(this.x, this.y);

 static ChangeNotifierProvider init(double x, double y) =>  ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => new DirectionProvider(),
          child; GoogleMaps(x,y);
          );


  final LatLng fromPoint = LatLng(-37.020125, -62.409388);
  @override
  _GoogleMapsState createState() => _GoogleMapsState();
}

class _GoogleMapsState extends State<GoogleMaps> {
  Position _currentPosition;
  LatLng toPoint;
  void initState() {
    _getCurrentLocation();
    var x2 = double.parse(widget.x);
    var y2 = double.parse(widget.y);
    toPoint = new LatLng(x2, y2);
    super.initState();
  }

  GoogleMapController _mapController;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Google Maps'),
      ),
      body:  Consumer<DirectionProvider>(
                    builder: (BuildContext context, DirectionProvider api,
                        Widget child) {
                      return GoogleMap(
                        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                          target: widget.fromPoint,
                          zoom: 12,
                        ),
                        markers: _createMarkers(),
                        polylines: api.currentRoute,
                        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                        myLocationEnabled: true,
                        myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.zoom_out_map),
        onPressed: _centerView,
      ),
    );
  }

  Set<Marker> _createMarkers() {
    var tmp = Set<Marker>();

    tmp.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId("FromPoint"),
      position: widget.fromPoint,
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "estoy aca"),
    ));

    tmp.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId("toPoint"),
      position: toPoint,
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "llegada"),
    ));
    return tmp;
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _mapController = controller;

    _centerView();
  }

  _centerView() async {
    var api = Provider.of<DirectionProvider>(context);

    await _mapController.getVisibleRegion();

    print("buscando direcciones");
    await api.findDirections(widget.fromPoint, toPoint);

    var left = min(
        widget.fromPoint.latitude, toPoint.latitude); //SE CALCULA COORDENADAS.
    var right = max(widget.fromPoint.latitude, toPoint.latitude);
    var top = max(widget.fromPoint.longitude, toPoint.longitude);
    var bottom = min(widget.fromPoint.longitude, toPoint.longitude);

    api.currentRoute.first.points.forEach((point) {
      left = min(left, point.latitude);
      right = max(right, point.latitude);
      top = max(top, point.longitude);
      bottom = min(bottom, point.longitude);
    });

    var bounds = LatLngBounds(
      southwest: LatLng(left, bottom),
      northeast: LatLng(right, top),
    );
    var cameraUpdate = CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50);
    _mapController.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
  }

  _getCurrentLocation() {
    var geolocator = Geolocator();
    var locationOptions = LocationOptions(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, distanceFilter: 10);

    StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream = geolocator.getPositionStream(locationOptions).listen((Position position) {
          print(position == null ? 'Unknown' : position.latitude.toString() + ', ' + position.longitude.toString());
        });
  }
}
```

Te recomiendo que repases bien el concepto de StatefulWidget antes de pasar a Provider, y también te paso el link de un canal de youtube que tengo junto con un amigo de Mexico, donde hablamos sobre State Management:  https://www.youtube.com/c/TheDartSide

Comment: Hola diego, hice lo segundo, aun así, persiste el problema. Mas detalles del error:

Comment: Could not find the correct Provider<DirectionProvider> above this GoogleMaps Widget
To fix, please:
 * Ensure the Provider<DirectionProvider> is an ancestor to this GoogleMaps Widget
 * Provide types to Provider<DirectionProvider>
 * Provide types to Consumer<DirectionProvider>
 * Provide types to Provider.of<DirectionProvider>()
 * Always use package imports. Ex: `import 'package:my_app/my_code.dart';
 * Ensure the correct `context` is being used.
If none of these solutions work, please file a bug at:
 https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues

Comment: Puedes poner tu codigo completo con la corrección que agregué, actualiza tu pregunta

Comment: listo. Ahi puse la clase completa

Comment: ya actualicé mi respuesta

Comment: Diego, como andas? Vi tus videos, aun asi, no puedo solucionar lo mio... Actualizo la pregunta

Comment: dentro del método `init` no estás usando `child` para llamar a GoogleMaps(),  además agrega el código sobre como llamas al widget de GoogleMaps.

Comment: Si, agregue el child para llamar a GoogleMaps, perdón. Pero sigue igual.

Comment: desde que widget llamas a GoogleMaps , puedes agregar esa parte del código ?

Comment: Listo Diego....

Comment: ok, como comenté en mi respuesta, no lo invoques así : GoogleMaps(x,y) ,  sino así :  GoogleMaps.init(x,y), de lo contrario no tendría sentido el método estatico que estamos creando

Comment: Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GoogleMaps.init(x,y));

Comment: listo diego, perdon, no habia entendido esa parte. Pero igualmente sigue con el eror -.- Hice un flutter Clean por las dudas. pero persiste.

Comment: hmm ahora si me parece raro, ya no debería marcar error, tienes el proyecto en algún repositorio donde pueda chequearlo ?

Comment: No lo tengo en ningún repositorio al momento, Si las normas de Stack lo permiten te podría mandar un mail.

Comment: ok, aunque sería mejor que lo subas a un repo como github, y luego me mandas el enlace a mi correo, que es como el nombre de mi usuario pero con gmail

Comment: https://github.com/emiibarra6/viviguamini

Comment: que clase es la q llama a googlemaps

Comment: La clase ButtonPurple

Comment: en el Package lista_detalle_nueva

Comment: creo q ya vi el error, en la linea 15 de GoogleMaps, te faltó declarar el tipo de objeto, en lugar de ChangeNotifierProvider( pon  ChangeNotifierProvider<DirectionProvider>(